# How to get my register taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, register-taxonomy

My taxonomy

```
    register_taxonomy(
        'king_blog_category', 
        'king_blogs',
         array(
            "hierarchical"          => true,
            "label"                 => "King blog Category",
            "singular_label"        => "label of taxonomy",
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug'              => 'king_blog_category',
                'with_front'        => true
            ),
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_tagcloud'         => true,
            '_builtin'              => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true
        )
    );
```

//Get method
//1:

```
$taxonomy = 'king_blog_category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
```

//2 :

```
$taxonomy = 'king_blog_category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0));
```

//Result :

```
array([invalid_taxonomy] => array([0] => Invalid taxonomy.))
```

Comment: What action do you register your taxonomy on and what file is that code in?

Comment: why are you setting `_builtin` attribute..? just curious since i don't know what it does. and you set some attributes, that are default to your values anyway, so why exactly do you set these..?

Answer (score 1):

`get_terms` first and only parameter should be an array. [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

```
get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'king_blog_category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => 0
]);
```

Comment: Same issue raised.

Comment: so what do you get, when you set this anywhere in your theme? header.php for example `$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {echo '<p>' . $taxonomy . '</p>';}`

Comment: category,

post_tag,

nav_menu,

link_category,

post_format,

portfolio-category,

product_type,

product_visibility,

product_cat,

product_tag,

product_shipping_class.

Comment: But get terms() function i will get king_blog_category and also worked my register taxonomy (category) in my ustom post type.

Comment: @raja that means, that your taxonomy, that you mention above, is not registered at all. to quote Milo: What action do you register your taxonomy on and what file is that code in?

Comment: my taxonomy shows in admin side / custom post type

Comment: $args = array(
                'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag','category','king_blog_category' ),

Comment: register_post_type( 'king_blogs', $args );

Comment: once again: What action do you register your taxonomy on and what file is that code in?

Comment: Taxonomy used in custom post type category.
Taxonomy code in my plugin file.

Comment: @rajasekar POST THAT CODE $§%§$W& not in the comments, place it inside the question so we can check if its all good. you only placed half of the required code, so how could anybody find the issue.. `get_taxonomies()` lists ALL existing taxonomies that are registered inside wordpress, so if yours is not in there, then it is not properly registered..